# Ubuntu Server license type

Tags: server, license

I am writing simple report for my company's board. Is that possible to simple tell what kind of license is used in Ubuntu Server?
I would like to know if thats possible to let the Ubuntu Server in basic configurations is "distributed under GPL" or "distributed under AGPL" etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is no single license for Ubuntu. Ubuntu is a distribution of thousands of different packages that each have their own license.

For example the Linux Kernel itself is released under the GPLv2, but other components like some binary drivers that may come with Ubuntu are proprietary.

This [page](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) explains this a bit further.